# Most elegant way to convert an array of even keys and odd values to a dictionary?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an array that has alternating keys and values because I don't know how to pass a dictionary in a GET in a url for the default binder.

the string array comes into the controller ok:

```
string[] values = new string[] {"123", "Pie", "456", "Cake"};
```

I need to convert it into a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<int,string> Deserts = new     Dictionary<int,string>() { {123, "Pie"}, {456, "Cake"} };
```

I tried:

```
values.ToDictionary(v => int.Parse(v), v => values.IndexOf(v) + 1);
```

but that gives an error at runtime. Index not found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using a for loop

```
var deserts = new Dictionary<int,string>();
for (var i = 0; i < values.Length; i += 2) {
    deserts.Add(int.Parse(values[i]), values[i+1]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple loop would do (and I would personally do it this way), but if you want to use LINQ you could use [`Windowed`](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/Windowed.cs) from [moreLINQ](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ) library. It would looks something like this:

```
values.Windowed(2).ToDictionary(v => int.Parse(v.First()), v => v.Last());
```

You could also get away without that with `Select`+`GroupBy`:

```
values.Select((Value, Index) => { Value, Index })
      .GroupBy(x => x.Index / 2)
      .ToDictionary(g => int.Parse(g.First().Value), g => g.Last().Value);
```

I wouldn't call it elegant though.

Comment: do you like `values.Where(v => values.IndexOf(v) % 2 == 0).ToDictionary(v => int.Parse(v), v => values[values.IndexOf(v) + 1]);`?

Comment: think about what has to happen to do that code toddmo, it's kind of bad

Comment: No. I would go with a for loop as showed by @Gonzalo. It's easier to read and simpler to understand. Also, your code will be less efficient because of double lookup.

Comment: multiple scans through the list plus indexof won't work well if you have the same string